# How to use a different user (other than postgres) for managing PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I will need to get PostgreSQL installed on some development/production machines in my company.

However, there are many restrictions:

First, I am not allowed to install it myself because I don't have root access and I am also not allowed to compile it from source. I will need to ask another team to install it from rpm.

Second, PostgreSQL will create/use the account "postgres" to start/stop/control it by default - but we want to use an existing account (e.g. "itdept") to manage (i.e. start/stop/etc.) it.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions/ideas. Thanks very much!